# Prove affine independence of these points

Tags: linear-algebra

I am having some trouble with this problem.
I want to prove that the following points are affine independent.

Let $k\geq 2$ and $i\in\{0,1,\dots,2k\}$ we define $S_i =(s_i^t)$ where $s_i^{i+2t (\bmod 2k+1)}=1$ for $t\in\{0,1,\dots,k-1\}$ and $s_i^t=0$ in the other cases, $s_i\in \mathbb{R}^{2k+1}$. Let now $X$ be defined as $\left\{ S_{i}\,:\, i\in\{0,1,\dots,2k\}\right\}$, I need to show that the points in $X$ are affine independent.

Any advice?

Regards,

John

Comment: I deleted the linear-programming tag, John. You put it back in. So far as I can see, your question has nothing to do with linear programming, so I took it out again.

Comment: I used the linear-programming tag because I learned the concept in a linear programming course. I thought that people related to that tag would be more familiar with the concept, but linear-programming is also adequate. Sorry for the inconvenience caused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $S_i$ are actually linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb R^{2k+1}$ so they are certainly affinely independent.

Let $P$ be the $(2k+1)\times(2k+1)$ matrix with general entry $t^j_i=1$ if $j\equiv i+1\hbox{ (mod $2k+1$)}$ and $0$ otherwise. This is the matrix of a linear tranformation that simply shifts the coordinates of every vector one position to the right (and the last coordinate becomes the first one).

Let $S$ be the matrix whose rows are the coordinates of the $S_i.$ Then

$$S=I+P^2+\ldots+P^{2(k-1)}$$

Because $P$ represents a coordinate shift, repeating it $2k+1$ times leaves every vector unchanged:

$$P^{2k+1}=I$$

and therefore all eigenvalues $\omega$ of $P$ are complex numbers that satisfy $\omega^{2k+1}=1.$ Apart from $\omega=1$ these numbers all satisfy $\omega^2\neq1$ and $\omega^{2k}\neq1.$

The eigenvalues $\lambda$ of $S$ all have the form

$$\lambda=1+\omega^2+\ldots+\omega^{2(k-1)}=\frac{1-\omega^{2k}}{1-\omega^2}$$

where the second equality holds only for $\omega\neq1$ but in any case all eigenvalues of $S,$ and thus its determinant, are nonzero. This shows that the rows of $S$ are linearly independent.

Comment: Thanks, but I actually don't know in this case the proof that a circulant matrix has those eigenvalues and I can't use this fact in my proof. It is usefull in a sense, but still not what I am looking for. But in any case, thank you for the answer.

Comment: I have rewritten the argument to avoid needing to know about circulant matrices.

Comment: Thank you, I have two questions about the argument. Can you clarify the meaning of $\omega$ and $\lambda$?

Comment: $\omega$ represents an arbitrary eigenvalue of $P$, for which I prove in the course of the argument that it must be a complex number whose $(2k+1)$-th power is equal to 1. $\lambda$ represents an arbitrary eigenvalue of $S,$ for which I prove in the end that it must be different from zero.

Comment: I get it, I was confused and I didn't realise that one was an eingenvalue of P and the other an eigenvalue of S. Thank you very much for all the help!